# VB.NET Post Request

Tags: vb.net

I have looked all over the place for VB.NET support on how to best run this POST request with a JSON, but I keep hitting a 401 Unauthorized error on every method I attempt. When I run this with the same JSON in python I have no issue.

I am using .NET 4.8.03752 and Visual Studio 2019

```
Public Class MyRequestData
    Public Property grant_type As String
    Public Property client_id As String
    Public Property client_secret As String
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property password As String
End Class

Public Class MyResponseData
    Public Property access_token As String
    Public Property refresh_token As String
End Class

Public Class OAuth
    Public Shared Async Sub Main()
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(768, SecurityProtocolType) Or CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
        Dim transaction As New MyRequestData With
        {
            .grant_type = "password",
            .client_id = "MYCLIENTID",
            .client_secret = "MYCLIENTSECRET",
            .username = "MYUSERNAME",
            .password = "MYPASSWORD"
        }
        Dim content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transaction)
        Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)
        Dim bytes = New Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(buffer)
        bytes.Headers.ContentType = New Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")

        Dim responseBody As String = Nothing
        Using client As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient
            Dim response = Await client.PostAsync("MYENDPOINT", bytes)
            responseBody = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using

        Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyResponseData)(responseBody)
        Debug.WriteLine(data)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: 401 means that the credentials you're using are invalid

Comment: I know they are correct because when I use the exact same json in python it works just fine :/

Comment: Can you compare the bytes of `buffer` with the equivalent bytes as generated by the Python version? I suggest saving them to disk to compare. (In .NET, you can use the [File.WriteAllBytes() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes).)

Comment: _I know they are correct_ - assuming you're referring to the id and password as being 'correct', it could be that the grant type, client id, and/or client secret don't match up with what the server is expecting.  Though depending on the server code, that may result in a 401, or it could result in a different https code.

Comment: @MarkL when I use the exact same JSON (grant_type, client_id, client_secret, username, password) in python the post request works just fine

Comment: Well, something is different.  You're not showing us the actual json being sent - your code is loading a class object then serializing it to json. As @AndrewMorton was suggesting, output and compare the actual request body data between this code and the working python code. Also check and compare all header elements between the two code sets. Do you own the server code, or have access to support for it? If so, ask the server guys what they don't like about this request.